# Apex Test Execution Stuck in Queue

Tags: apex

I have attempting to run an Apex Test Execution and my test has been stuck in "Queue" since yesterday. It doesn't look as though I , as the Admin, have been locked but still no progress on the queue. I have selected "Abort", tried running the test in a different browser. I have also tried Clearing the test data, closing and then reopening the developer console.

I am still stuck in Queue. Has any one had this issue in the past? If so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, you should ask there as well.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I thought that was where I posting but I see I was in the wrong screen. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the queue would be resumed after a while.  If you still have issues, you'd have to log case to Salesforce